# Put check this checkbox with selenium in ruby programing

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to put check this checkbox with selenium in ruby programing.
but i can`t do put check. how should I do?

Now, I make below code.

```
# code
element = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*
[@id="lookCheck10"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/label')
@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element); 



# html
<div class="e-select-box p-look-bike__type-box">
    <div class="e-title">
       <input type="hidden" name="data[Reserve][types][10]" 
  id="lookCheck10_" value="0"/><input type="checkbox" 
name="data[Reserve][types][10]"  id="lookCheck10" value="1" 
checked="checked"/>                         <label 
for="lookCheck10">BIKE</label>
    </div>
    <div class="e-media">
        <div class="e-media__body p-look-bike__type-detail">
            <p>this is good for family</p>
        </div>
        <div class="e-media__image p-look-bike__type-image">
            <img src="/images/reserve/img_biketype_10.jpg" alt="bike">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: i dont see any error ?

Comment: could you put checking into the checkbox? i can not put checking with this code..

Comment: @yoyo Why are performing Javascript click rather than simply use the selenium click?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to select a checkbox with label 'BIKE'. For that, use below code-

```
element = @driver.find_element(:xpath, '//*[@id="lookCheck10"]')
@driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting Javascript click rather than suggesting selenium click?

Comment: I assumed Selenium click didn't work that's why user tried javascript click. What is the problem with javascript click?

Comment: Okay! Javascript click doesn't wait If click triggers the page load. But when you use selenium click, you are depended on corresponding driver to click, Firefox driver and Chrome driver waits for page load if click causes page load. Recently added Geckodriver for firefox doesn't wait but legacy firefox driver does.